# How do I create a RAM disk on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, files, linux-mint, performance, ramdisk

I am running a package that adds data to the end of 140–300 files each time through the process.

I'm thinking of moving the process to a RAM disk, and using `rsync` to copy it back when done. My goal is to reduce wear by eliminating disk head seeks.

Will this work? If so, how do I go about creating the RAM disk?

Comment: Have you benchmarked it? The kernel already buffers writes, so the data won't be written as long as there's memory available. Have you actually observed all those disk seeks, or are you just imagining them?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that this can work if you do have enough ram for the process's demands. I propose using tmpfs instead of ramfs; this way you 'll prevent kernel hiccups when out of ram.

Just create a mount point and then mount a tmpfs on it (like [here](http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux)):

```
 # mkdir /mnt/tmpfs.ramdisk
 # mount -t tmpfs -o size=100M tmpfs /mnt/tmpfs.ramdisk
```

You can of course add a permanent entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs   /mnt/tmpfs.ramdisk  tmpfs  nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=100M 0  0
```